# HTML5 Audio vs. Videojs - play m3u8

Tags: stream, video.js, rtmp, m3u8

I would like to run the following audio stream:
https://stream.itv.az/rtmp:/radio/chunks.m3u8
via standard html5 via audio tag.
But the stream does NOT work with standard HTML5 :-(

I found out a free plugin **videojs** would run this stream.
Yes it does. It works on my computer, but it does not work on **iPhone / iOS**.
After ca. 30 secs, the stream interrupts and I have to press the play button on iPhone.

**What did I do so far?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Streaming</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     function run() {
        var player = videojs('#player', { controls: true }, {'nativeAudioTracks': false, 'nativeVideoTracks': false, 'hls': { 'overrideNative': true } });        
        player.playsinline(true);            
     }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="run()">

    <audio id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" style="height:100px; width:300px" controls >
        <source src="https://stream.itv.az/rtmp:/radio/chunks.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

- Anyone who can tel me what to change in my code, to be able to run the stream "permanently"?
- If not possible at all with videojs, which any other license-free plugin can play the (rtmp?) stream?

Many Thanks, BM

Comment: [A shot in the dark] : I think I read somewhere that certain browsers won't let a video/audio that initially starts in a playing state, continue to play unless the audio begins in the 'muted' state.  If so, try adding the 'muted' attribute inside your audio-tag.

Comment: I have added following line in the run function: 
player.muted(true);  

The stream starts once user press the play button,
so it does not start automatically.

Again, on iPhone the streams works ca. 30 Secs.
then it stops. :(

Comment: The problem will be the stream, not the code. iOS plays HLS natively and can only play it natively (on other browsers Video.js uses its own playback engine with the MSE API).

Comment: David/Misterbe:
I will search for another stream of this channel.
I hope this will help !

Many Thanks for your responses.